# The Aliyot in Parshat Bereisheet

Tags: parashat-bereishit, torah-service, nusach-ashkenaz

According to the Hertz (Soncino Press) chumash, the aliyot for Bereisheet are (excuse my poor formatting)

Aliyah...….      begins at

2...…………..1:14

3...………….1:24

4...…………..2:4

5...…………..3:22

6...…………...5:1

7...…………….5:25

The Artscroll (Stone edition) has them at

2...………...2:4

3...………….2:20

4...………...3:22

5...………...4:19

6...………..4:23

7...………….5:25

I won't try to get into how the Aliyah breaks are devised or why there is a difference here, but I do note that the Hertz has the following notes:

at 2:4, "sheini lsf'"

at 2:20, "shlishi lsf'"

at 3:22, "revi'i lsf"

at 4:19, "chamishi lsf"

[he does not have a special note for shishi even though his place for shishi is different from the Stone edition's]

I can't speak for what happened in any other nominally Ashkenazic shul, but in the one I went to, we used the Artscroll aliyot, thus opting for what Hertz labeled as the "Sf'" practice (I think he means "Sephardi" not Nusach Sefard - the table of abbreviations on page 1053 just reads "Sephardi"). If they are for Sf, why would they be accepted in an Ashkenazic setting?

Comment: Ultimately you can break the aliyos wherever you want. As long as you have (at least) seven of them, that none of them start in the middle of a parshah less than three pesukim from either end of the parshah, that each Aliyah is at least three pesukim long, then it doesn’t matter where the aliyos are. The minhag is to read particular aliyos, but the Halacha is to read aliyos. Even each week’s Sidra is minhag (even as the concept of reading each week is d’Oraisa).

Comment: My shul uses Hertz and as I was used to my Tikkun app (I think it's a Rusty Brick app?) has the breaks as Stone chumash. I warned the rabbi and the gabb'im, but they were still a bit lost. I gather that there is some minhag that the reading for all the days should not be split. I can't say for the reasoning of the position of the other aliyot. Obviously, there is no complete concensus on the position of the aliyot. @DonielF's last sentence alludes to a far more extensive area mentioned in a comprehensive article I found, recently. See http://www.hakirah.org/vol%202%20epstein.pdf if interested.

Comment: My concern is not so much about the breaks but about the labeling of these as "Sf" but opted for in an Ashkenazi shul.